# How to delete Gnome Panel?

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel

I am trying to get rid of my Gnome panels so that I can go to a purely Docky/Gnome-Do environment.

I have got rid of everything, except for a single remaining panel which I cannot delete.

The text "Delete this panel" is greyed out - any pointers about how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't used gnome for a while, but I used to do that with [gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor).

Open "desktop >> gnome >> session >> required_components", then double-click the "panel" option, then remove the "gnome-panel" value and close it, then just:

`killall gnome-panel`

Last time I used this method was with Karmic tho.

Comment: This works fine in 10.10.

Comment: One could argue you should change this to whatever docky needs to launch.

Answer (score 6):

What I like to do is make the GNOME panel part of the [Compiz widget layer](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Widget). That way I can quickly pull up the panel with a hotkey in case I ever need it.

In [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager), set Desktop -> Widget Layer -> Behavior -> Widget Windows to `class=Gnome-panel`. Fine-tune the other Widget Layer settings to your preference.

Comment: I like the elegance of this. Having a tried-and-tested fallback is handy when things break.

Answer (score 1):

This also works with Natty Narwhal 11.04.

Open terminal and type

`rm ~/.gconf/apps/panel/general/%gconf.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24957/how-to-delete-disable-gnome-panels-no-existing-solutions-working/24961#24961) may help.  I figure you can likely do the same with docky that you do with AWN.

```
gconftool-2 --type=string --set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/panel 'docky'
```

Answer (score -1):

i solve it by just uninstalling and re-installing compiz manager.

Comment: Can you edit this answer to provide detailed instructions for how you do this?