# How to delete/disable GNOME panels? (Existing solutions not working.)

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel, gconf

I would like to remove the GNOME panel completely. I spend most of my time in a (`tmux`) terminal or a browser. Synapse and a small hidden AWN panel fit the rest of my needs.

I have tried all recommended solutions including this (found it a few places):

- [How to delete Gnome Panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6147/how-to-delete-gnome-panel)

However it always comes back at log in. I have tried changing the required components > panel to avant-whatever as well as to empty. I have tried setting them both as default (right click set as default).

Right now I just have the last panel set to transparent and auto hide, but it still tends to be annoying.

What do I need to do to get rid of this damn thing?

**Clarification:**

Using gconf-editor, gconftool2, and/or Ubuntu tweak to set `/desktop/gnome/session/required_component/panel` to `avant-window-navigator` is **not working**. The setting stays when I reboot, but the empty gnome panel sticks around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an explanation of how to replace gnome-panel with awn on the [AWN FAQ](http://wiki.awn-project.org/FAQ#How_do_I_set_up_GNOME_session_to_start_Awn_instead_of_GNOME_Panel.3F)

> If you have "Configuration Editor"
>   (AKA gconf-editor) installed, run it
>   and navigate to the key folder
>   /desktop/gnome/session/required_components.
>   Double-click on the key panel in the
>   right-hand pane to edit it, and change
>   the value to "avant-window-navigator"
>   followed by the "OK" button.
>   Alternatively, you can run the
>   following command from the terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --type=string --set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/panel 'avant-window-navigator'
```

I did this on my laptop the other day and it worked fine.  As a side note, to bring gnome-panel back:

```
gconftool-2 --type=string --set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/panel 'gnome-panel'
```

Comment: This is the way everybody recommends. I have used this method perfectly on my laptop. However my desktop has one panel that defies removal.

Comment: @alan-peabody That's strange.  That means that gnome-panel must still be running.  What happens when you run ` ps -A | grep panel` in the console?

I haven't tried this, but maybe you could find and remove the panel from `~/.gnome/apps/panel/toplevels` (I'd probably back that directory up first before messing with it).   Also, is it possible that that extra panel is the wingpanel app or something?  I know when I installed it, it looked like some misc. empty panel.

Comment: `ps -A` lists:  `2193 ?        00:00:00 gnome-panel`

The directory you mentioned does not exist. I do have a `~/.gnome2/panel2.d/` directory.

I have not installed wingpanel, although the original mock up certainly was appealing.

Comment: Actually I DID have wingpanel installed (dunno what late night I did that...). Removing it solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @alan-peabody You might still want to find out why gnome-panel is running if you've explicitly told gnome not to start it.  Otherwise I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

I failed completely to disable the GNOME Panel in the standard GNOME sessions on Precise (12.04). But I tried [this script](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2012/05/script-for-installing-awn-in-precise.html) and it worked for me, adding a new session option on the LightDM login screen.