# black line across top of display in virtualbox guest

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, display

As you can see from the screen shot below, there is a display problem in my virtualbox guest running on an Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit host, using dual monitors.

The line does not appear on the monitor the mouse pointer is on, only the other one.

I am running the latest Virtualbox (4.1.14) with GuestAdditions installed.

[image]

Any suggestions for how to resolve this?

Comment: This issue has been resolved for me by a recent update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's the Panel's shadow.
Just make sure your panel is not "transparent":

Launch the CompizConfig Settings Manager, go to the Ubuntu Unity Plugin, on the Experimental tab there are two Panel Opacity options you can tweak.

Comment: setting panel opacity to its lowest value (0.01) did fix the problem in virtualbox, but now I have very transparent panel :S

Comment: but what's the problem? do you wan't to completely [get rid of the panel](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6147/how-to-delete-gnome-panel)?

Comment: the problem (from my original post) is that I shouldn't see the panel when I am running the guest os in virtualbox. although changing the opacity of the panel DOES resolve this issue in vbox, it's not a great solution overall because now my panel is transparent.

Comment: Ah... Ok... I guess I've got it now. Probably a bug in VirtualBox? I haven't tried it on 12.04 yet.